# Google Analytics MCF Showing Incorrect Data - Segment

Tags: google, analytics, google-ads

We are using segment.io (segment.com) for a SaSS website. Currently the Multi-Channel funnel data for "Top Conversion Paths" is showing some "unavailable" even though we have updated the the Display Advertisers Features in Segment for the tracking.

Adwords data is linked and gclid is working as the data is showing up fine in the Adwords Reporting in Google Analytics.

[image: MCF by Channel Grouping]

However if we look at the paths by Source Medium you can see google/cpc which is still not showing properly :(

[image: MCF by Source Medium]

Thanks,
Vincent

Comment: same issue here, no idea what's causing it and Google search unsuccessful.